# dockerfile will not use cache for most of instruction because of COPY . /app

Tags: docker, caching

I'm trying to make a deployable docker image with my laravel app.

So I use

```
COPY . /app
```

on the beginning on the dockerfile
,
But then, each time I change the dockerfile, it will cache until     `COPY . /app`

In my case, I need my files to execute `composer install`, so each time I modify my dockerfile and rebuild, Il will have to download again my composer dependencies (and it lasts a long)

I already put the COPY instuctions as far as I can, so for example, I don't have to do apt-get instructions again and again.

Is there any way to "ignore" changes made to dockerfile, for better caching ?